# OSGi Aries Blueprint static field

Tags: java, spring, osgi, htmlunit, blueprint

I need to create a bean that takes a class instance as a constructor parameter. The useful values of this class instance are created by the class as static fields.

Specifically, I am trying to create WebClient beans from HtmlUnit. http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html

You can see that WebClient takes a no-arg constructor (do not want), as well as one that takes a BrowserVersion instance.
http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/BrowserVersion.html

BrowserVersion defines the useful instances as static fields, eg: CHROME, FIREFOX_24, INTERNET_EXPLORER_11.

I need to reference one of these BrowserVersion instances in an Aries Blueprint bean.

Here is what the blueprint setup looks like:

```
<bean id="webClient" class="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient">
    <argument>??</argument>
</bean>
```

I have tried:

```
<argument><bean class="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24" /></argument>
<argument value="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24" />
```

I also tried just creating a BrowserVersion bean in the blueprint config, and I can't seem to make that work either.

```
<bean id="webClient" class="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient">
    <argument>
        <bean class="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion">
            <argument index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="Netscape" />
            <argument index="1" type="java.lang.String" value="5.0 (Windows)" />
            <argument index="2" type="java.lang.String" value="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0" />
            <argument index="3" type="java.lang.Float"  value="24.0" />
        </bean>
    </argument>
</bean>
```

That should match [a public constructor](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/BrowserVersion.html#BrowserVersion(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20float)) on BrowserVersion.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong on either count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked around it by using a helper method.

```
<bean id="webClient" class="com.stackoverflow.HtmlUnitHelper" factory-method="getChromeClient" />
```

The helper method is simply:

```
public static WebClient getChromeClient() {
    return new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
}
```

Perhaps there is a better solution, but this works!